# In Hive metastore db, How can I get the update_time of alter table

Tags: mysql, hive, metastore

I had change the table in Hive using "alter table " like this.

```
alter table tbl_name add columns (...);
alter table tbl_name change col1 col2 string comment 'test';
```

In the table `TBLS` of Hive metastore database, it only record the create_time of the table. How can I get the update time of *alter table*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below command

> desc formatted tbl_name

and look for *last_modified_time*

it will give you when it was last updated.
it will be in unixtimestamp.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to know what tables are modified today. first "show tables" get all tables, then use this command one by one and filter the last_modified_time, any simple way?